# Turn off CPU turbo-boost for a process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-frequency

When the CPU (Intel i5-8400) is heavily loaded, the fan seems to increase its speed and make noise.

I want to eliminate the noise when running CPU-intensive backup process (`backup2l` program). (It is apparently CPU-intensive because of compressing backup with `gzip`.)

How to make a process not to use turbo boost?

My OS is Ubuntu Linux 18.10.

If such a feature is not available in Linux, we should report a feature suggestion.

Comment: Consider using `nice` ..

Comment: @tink I already have `nice -n 19 backup2l -b` but this seems not to work. Should we report feature suggestion to prevent turbo boost for `nice` processes?

Comment: If nice doesn't do the trick consider `cpulimit` or using `cgroups`.

Comment: Aiui nice is for priority, cpulimit is what you want. Also, you may want to change fan settings in your "BIOS", but careful not to overheat anything.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the turbos kick in because the BIOS figures it needs the additional cooling because of the CPU doing a lot of hard work. If you shut off the additional cooling but don't decrease the workload, you're going to have a bad time...

Comment: What kind of CPU is it, and which distribution are you running?  It's possible that you can do this with frequency scaling, but without those details, I can't say which package(s) you'd need to install.

Comment: @JigglyNaga i5-8400, Ubuntu Linux 18.10 (I initially wrote that I use Ubuntu Linux, but someone edited my question removing it)

Comment: @porton Thank you very much.  Although the community decided to reject your edit as "conflicts with author's original intent", I think it's a valuable edit, so have manually included it again...  **;-)**  **+1** to the question for the effort.   **0:-)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what `cpulimit` is for:

```
cpulimit --exe=gzip --background --limit=100
cpulimit --exe=tar --background --limit=100
```

this will limit the total CPU usage of the most CPU-resource intensive programs used by the `backup2l` script to 100% per core.  If that would still make too much noise, reduce that number until your machine is quiet again.

After `backup2l` is finished, just `killall cpulimit` to go back to normal operations.

<sub>**Note:** your backup might take twice as long if you limit it  to only 2 cores just like a car: the faster, the noisier...</sub>

Comment: When I started it manually with `--monitor-forks`, I had at least a few tens (maybe hundreds) of `cpulimit` processes and my system became nearly unrespponsible

Comment: And note that cpulimit will use kill -CONT and kill -STOP to emulate this behaviors. (Maybe I am wrong about that)

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/local/bin/myproclimitator`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
PIDNUM=$1

while sleep 1;do 
 kill -CONT $PIDNUM
 sleep 0.1
 kill -STOP $PIDNUM || exit 
done
```

Call it like:

```
myproclimitator pidnum
```

Comment: This is wonderful, I also once thought SIGSTOP was a golden ticket... except a lot of processes will not expect being stopped constantly. Tell me which complex processes that tolerate being stopped once every 100ms, please.

Comment: All process should be fine, because this is similar from what multitask system does to run more than one process in a single cpu for example.

Comment: Shouldbe and reallyis are two different universes. Try it on some big fat processes.

Comment: Not. What is happening?

Comment: Inconsistency if the sighandlers aren’t obedient?

Comment: Inconsistency like what?  Are you saying stop doesn't stop and cont doesn't continues?

Comment: I am saying that. Try various UNIX-like and UNIX-derived systems. In any case this will not affect CPU-boost.

Comment: So it is unfortunelly a practical problem, but in theory it should not do this. It is working for you or not  ?

Comment: That has always seemed to depend on the program and the system itself.

Comment: Please be more specific If you already know that, why you ask me ?

Comment: I don’t know, so I ask you (which complex programs tolerate being throttled by sending them SIGCONT SIGSTOP)

Comment: My acknowledge is limited for now to this: It should not have any trouble without any program. But if it is not working nice for your programs, please be much more specific what exactly you are trying to execute and what exactly is running in trouble, and how it is broken, it runs slow, it reboot the machine, it freezes everything, etc. And much more like how many memory you have, the size of files you are processing Maybe you should openning a new question being specific or increase/decrease the sleep times..

Comment: Inconsistency in program memory was the culprit.

Comment: My acknowledge is limited for now to this: It should not have any trouble without any program. Open a new question and try to be more specific. Show a running example. Maybe someone can help you better.

Comment: I don’t have any problem, mainly because I don’t SIGSTOP my processes every 100 milliseconds. I was commenting.

Comment: Neither I. I really believe in you, but I just cannot imagine a logical reason for the problem you describe. Are you pretty sure that everyone has this problems? This inconsistencies you experienced are not related to time or date ? I will test more when I am at home.

Answer (score 4):

From [Processor boosting control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt):

> ```
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost
> ```
>
> controls the boost setting for the whole system. You can read and write
>   that file with either "0" (boosting disabled) or "1" (boosting allowed).

This is a global setting, so writing a `0` there will prevent *all* processes from using boost and making a noise.

Comment: I do not want all processes to stop use boosts. So your answer is not to my question.